# Validacion de celda en DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validación, datagridview

Necesito que en ciertas celdas de un DataGridView solo el usuario introduzca números enteros, cuando el usuario presione una tecla que no sea un número, el código no la escriba o muestre un mensaje. Estoy utilizando el evento "***KeyPress***", este evento me funciona bien en los TextBox, pero en los DataGridView al parecer no se lleva a cabo, cuando el usuario presiona una tecla, ¿o me falta algo por agregar? ¿Cómo se hace validación cuando se presiona una tecla en una celda de un DataGridView? El código es el siguiente;

```
 private void dGV_piezas_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int fila = selFila;
        int celda = dGV_piezas.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        if (celda == 0) //Cantidad de piezas.
        {
            if ((e.KeyChar >= 32 && e.KeyChar <= 47) || (e.KeyChar >= 58 && e.KeyChar <= 255))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Solo entero", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La flecha indica la celda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que tenemos que hacer es crear el evento que nos va a validar que lo que escribimos es un número. Un evento se implementa como si se tratase de un método(para que entiendas mejor, aunque no son exactamente lo mismo). Este evento lo tienes que crear manualmente y lo que hará es que solo permitirá escribir si el caracter es un número o se presiona la **tecla BackSpace**:

```
private void Grid_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !((Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (Char)Keys.Back));
}
```

Posteriormente marcamos nuestro **DataGridView** y en el **ToolBox** en la parte de los eventos seleccionamos al evento **EditingControlShowing**(Este no lo creas tú lo genera **Visual Studio** como mismo se genera automáticamente el **evento OnClick** de un botón por ejemplo).

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = e.Control as TextBox;

    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
       if (txt != null)
       {
          txt.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Grid_KeyPress);
          txt.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Grid_KeyPress);
       }
   }
   else
   {
      txt.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Grid_KeyPress);
   }
}
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es que la celda que seleccionamos la convertimos en un control **TextBox**, al tratarla como un **TextBox** podemos lograr que funcione como el **evento KeyPress** de un **TextBox**. Después preguntamos si la celda sobre la que estamos escribiendo tiene su índice de columna igual a **0**, lo cual quiere decir que es la primera columna, de ser cierto esto entonces preguntamos si **txt** no es nulo(para evitar una excepción por una referencia nula), después vienen estas líneas:

```
txt.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Grid_KeyPress);
txt.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Grid_KeyPress);
```

Aquí quitamos y añadimos el evento que creamos previamente(**Grid_KeyPress**) al **evento KeyPress** del **TextBox**. Entonces al llegar aquí se ejecutará el **evento KeyPress** del **TextBox** y se ejecutará el evento que previamente habíamos creado, de ser número o **BackSpace** se escribirá, caso contrario no se escribirá(solamente para las celdas cuyo índice de columna sea igual a **0**). En caso de que el índice de columna de la celda seleccionada no sea **0** pues podrás escribir cualquier cosa. Te recomiendo que busques más información sobre **eventos** y **delegados** en Internet.

Por último te comento que a través de la **clase Char** puedes saber que tipo de caracter se escribe:

```
Char.IsNumber //Números
Char.IsLetter //Letras
Char.IsLetterOrDigit //Alfanúmericos
```

Y otros más.

La prueba yo la hice para que solo se permitan números, tú puedes adaptar  este código a tus necesidades.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias.